# How to create a specific ratio in a chain of gears with fixed locations?

Tags: geometry, circles

On a number line, there are $n$ pegs at integer positions $a_0, a_1, ..., a_n$ where $a_n > a_{n-1}$ and $a_0 = 0$. On each peg, there is a gear with a radius that can be adjusted to any positive rational number. Can I set the radius of the first wheel to some radius $r$ such that adjusting all the other wheels so that they turn properly results in the final wheel having a radius $\frac12r$? If so, what is that radius?

I've been able to come up with a handful of solutions for a handful of specific cases, but nothing general. For example, in the most trivial case, with just two pegs, one at $0$ and one at $a_1$, the solution is just $r=\frac23a_1$. Similarly, if there is an even number of pegs an equal distance apart, the solution is also $\frac23a_1$. This is because adding the two gears in the middle causes the chain to go from $\frac23\rightarrow\frac13$ to $\frac23\rightarrow\frac13\rightarrow\frac23\rightarrow\frac13$, meaning it doesn't create any meaningful change in the system.

Another simple case is when there are three equally spaced pegs. There is no solution in this case because, in order to make the gears touch, the first and last gears must be the same size. This also applies in any case with an odd number of equally spaced pegs, for the same reasoning as the even-numbered case does.

The final thing I was able to prove is a general solution for the three peg case. Because the gear at $a_1$ has a fixed radius, then $$a_1 - r = a_2 - a_1 -\frac12r$$ assuming the conditions $0<r<a_1$ and $\frac12r<2a_1-b$ hold. By rearranging I got $$r= 4a_1 -2a_2$$ which is correct, as far as I can tell.

I can't seem to come up with anything more general, it feels like I am missing something obvious. Is there a more general solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $r_k$ is the radius of the gear centred at $a_k$ ($r_0=r$), it is not difficult to show that:
$$
r_k=a_k-2a_{k-1}+2a_{k-2}-\dots\pm 2a_1\mp r.
$$
From there you can get an answer to your question.